# Does entropy depend on what we can measure?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

This idea has been bouncing around in my mind for a few days.

The modern definition of entropy is "the number of microstates corresponding to a given macrostate": $S = k \log W$. In a thermodynamic system, the macrostate is usually defined by a set of state variables, such at pressure, volume, and temperature (PVT). These variables gives a complete description of the macroscopic state.

However, let's say that I can measure pressure and volume, but not temperature (thermometers have yet to be invented). Then as far as I know, the macroscopic state of a system is *just* PV. Does this mean the entropy should count the number of microstates with that pressure and volume, regardless of temperature? Do I just plug in a different number for $W$ and get a different entropy, or is the entropy an intrinsic property of a system?